# FileReader and BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I have 3 methods

1. for open file
2. for read file
3. for return things read in method read

this my code :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication56;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author x
 */
public class RemoteFileObjectImpl extends java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject  implements RemoteFileObject
{
    public RemoteFileObjectImpl() throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    File f = null;
    FileReader r = null;
    BufferedReader bfr = null;

    String output = "";
    public void open(String fileName) {
        //To read file passWord
        f = new File(fileName);
    }
    public String readLine() {
        try {
            String temp = "";
            String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            r = new FileReader(f);
            while ((temp = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
                output += temp + newLine;
                bfr.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output;
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            bfr.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) throws RemoteException{
        RemoteFileObjectImpl m = new RemoteFileObjectImpl();
        m.open("C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\txt.txt");
        m.readLine();
        m.close();
    } 
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: "does not work" is not good enough. Explain what you expected and what you got instead.

Comment: These errors appear when the work of Ran and I do not know why.?


 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javaapplication56.RemoteFileObjectImpl.readLine(RemoteFileObjectImpl.java:51)
     at javaapplication56.RemoteFileObjectImpl.main(RemoteFileObjectImpl.java:73)

Comment: Again: what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: @Seetah We are not going to inspect all your code or copy it simply to try to find what you would expect. It's like a consultation with a doctor, tell us your symptoms and we can then look for a cure.

Comment: Now we are talking @Seetah now that tells you and us exactly what the problems is (updated my answer below). Line 51 is using a variable that is null.

Comment: I want to pass a file from the server to the client and the client reads the file, but only in the code is not read < sorry my english so bad i hope so you understand me

Comment: No problem, I described your problem and provided a solution in my updated answer below. Just please remember to describe your problem better the next time, "does not work"  is hard to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect it to do, you are not doing anything with the line you read, just

```
m.readLine();
```

Instead:

```
String result = m.readLine();
```

or use the `output` variable that you saved.

Do you want to save it to a variable, print it, write it to another file?

Update: after your update in the comments:
Your variable `bfr` is never created/initialized. You are only doing this:

```
r = new FileReader(f);
```

so `bfr` is still `null`.

You should do something like this instead:

```
bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
```

Comment: `r = new FileReader(f);` so that's one less step.

Comment: Umm, well @Neil the code is not using `r` though, it is using `bfr`, so you better change that or initialize `bfr`. Besides `FileReader` doesn't have `readLine`, `BufferedReader` does.

Comment: Well, I guess he doesn't need to save the intermediate file reader, but wouldn't `bfr = new BufferedReader(r);` have worked?